# Shell script to list all subdirectories recursively within a folder that contains files with an specific extension

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a folder named a, and it may have one or multiple sub-directories and the sub-directories may have multiple sub-directories and so on. I want to know how can I write a shell script to list all the sub-directories that contain a file with specific extension.

So, it may be like

```
A -> B -> C

  -> D -> f2.txt

       -> F -> f3.txt

  -> E -> G -> H -> f4.txt
```

So only D, F and H directories will be listed. Actually I need this as a quick way to find the package names of particular java classes, by listing their directory tree. For example in the previous example A.E.G.H is a package same as A.D, but A.E.G is not a package as G only contains a sub directory H no files.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why I received a negative vote? I did some research before posting here. And I did not find any suitable solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need `find` command. You can use like this,

```
find . -name '*.txt'
```

Here,

`.` - dot(`.`) is current directory. You can also specify the path where to start.

`-name` - file name to find.

You can also use `-maxdepth` option to limit the depth of recursive finding. Normally, `find` will find the file recursively.

**Update:**

If you want to list out the directories,

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec dirname {} \;
```

Comment: Hi I do not want to list the files, only the directories.

Comment: @bobah's solution already gives the answer to that. It's also simpler than calling an extrenal tool like `dirname`.

Comment: @konsolebox bobah's solution gives me the following error, find: -printf: unknown primary or operator. it may be the reason that I am using Mac.

Comment: @sat any idea how can I remove the duplicate entries?

Comment: @Pbasak, Like this: `find . -name '*.txt' -exec dirname {} \; | sort | uniq`

Answer (score 1):

`find . -name '*.txt' -printf '%h\n'`

`man find` will give other possible format flags usable with `-printf`

Comment: Hi, this solution gives me the following error, find: -printf: unknown primary or operator. it may be the reason that I am using Mac.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler and faster alternative for systems like MAC. No need to use 2 additional tools and even repeatingly call `dirname`:

```
find -type f -name '*.txt' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}{--NF}!a[$0]++'
```

`-type f` may be removed optionally if it doesn't work.

Comment: I only need the directory listing not the files. This gives me the file listing by the way.

Comment: yes, it came with directory and file names. well let me try again.

Comment: @Pbasak Your awk probably behaves differently. e.g. `nawk`